# Computed column must be in the GROUP BY list in INSERT VALUES

Tags: sql, h2

I have a table that holds log lines, and added some computed columns:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS log_lines (
    id          identity NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    time_stamp  bigint NOT NULL,

    -- some other columns here ...

    type_text   varchar NOT NULL,
    flag_text   varchar NOT NULL,

    -- computed columns
    shield      boolean NOT NULL AS type_text LIKE '%Shield%',

    -- some other computed columns here ...
    -- all BOOLEAN columns computed from values of the VARCHAR columns

);
```

When i try to insert a row into this table:

```
INSERT
  INTO log_lines ( time_stamp, ... , type_text, flag_text )
  VALUES ( 123456789, ... , '', '' )
```

H2 throws a weird error

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "SHIELD" must be in the GROUP BY list; SQL statement:
INSERT
INTO LOG_LINES ( TIME_STAMP, ... , TYPE_TEXT, FLAG_TEXT )
VALUES ( 123456789, ... , '', '' ) [90016-182]
```

I am really lost here...

### EDIT

Just after posting the question i found the solution to why was an error thrown.

The culprit was another computed column, that was declared before `shield` and was computed from it. Moved that computed column to the end of the `CREATE TABLE` statement, and it is working just fine.

---

But the question of "What does the error mean?" remains...